# Unable to enter a value in a field using XPath with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to enter a value in the textbox by using XPath with Selenium automated scripts.

Please help to correct my code.

```
IWebElement name= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='text' and @name='name']"));
name.SendKeys("juana");
```

Comment: [Read on Selenium](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-find-element-by-text/) here and see how they use `text()` to check the data. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Write and Earn']"));`

Comment: This will search for the Text Box containing the text "Write and Earn",right? I need to push value to the Text Box.

Comment: Yes. Once you find that element, update the inner text of that element with the new value